# DIV anchor tag : Make inner div alone clickable

Tags: html, anchor, mouseover

```
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgreen; height: 30px">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
        <div
            style="border: 1px solid red; width: 40%; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; height: 29px;">
            <div style="padding-top: 6px; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 45%;">Flights</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here i need the *mouse-over hand icon* to come only on the inner div (div with red border).
Actually I have given the anchor tag to the inner div alone.. But it comes for the outer one also..!!

Briefly explained in this picture : http://awesomescreenshot.com/01b1ctcn55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `display:table-caption;` to the inner div.

Here is the [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sKGxd/).

**The Code:**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgreen; height: 30px;">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
        <div
            style="border: 1px solid red; width: 40%; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; height: 29px; display:table-caption;">
            <div style="padding-top: 6px; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 45%;">Flights</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great ! That was a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

The inner and the outer div are almost of the same height, are you sure it is the outer div with the border and not the inner one?

Comment: Yes, both are in same height. Even if i decrease the height the hand-mouse-pointer comes in left and right side of the inner div. 

Yes, it is the outer. That's why I tried with colored border :)

Answer (score 0):

You encapsulate the nested div's with an "a" tag which makes everything in there a link. Try this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgreen; height: 30px">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 40%; margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%; height: 29px;">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">
      <div style="padding-top: 6px; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 45%;">
        Flights
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this, only the inner div becomes a link. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8HG9N/8/

Comment: FYI, If you move your mouse just over 2-3 pixels above the bottom red border going into the button, it does not work. For that an extra code with `padding-bottom: 6px;` needs to be inserted to the inner div with the flight text. - @Robert